# Implementing forward proxy in Java/Spring Boot

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, proxy, java-8, servlet-filters

I'm interested in learning more about HTTP and how proxies work by building my own (simple) forward proxy using Java 8 and Spring Boot. The article I read (and am interested in implementing) is [here](https://www.citrix.com/blogs/2010/02/25/netscaler-feature-of-the-day-deploy-as-a-forward-proxy/). The main three forward proxy features I'm interested in are:

- **Resource caching** : If a static resource (CSS, JS, media file, etc.) has been accessed before, we can grab it right off the proxy's local (file system) cache
- **User tracing/auditing** : We can inspect HTTP headers to see who is making request to which target URLs, and perhaps write these access records to a log
- **Content Filtering** : URL filtering, possibly inspecting the response from the target site and protecting against malware downloads, etc.

The goal here is to build this proxy as a Spring Boot app, run it locally, and then configure a browser to use this local proxy. Eventually I'll deploy it to a non-local environment, but first things first.

I'm not really concerned about the implementation details of these features - I can figure out how to write/implement them. What I'm wondering is: what is the best Spring/JavaEE construct for *providing* these types of capabilities? Java EE servlet filter? Spring Controller? Some other (perhaps AOP-based) construct?

Again, the idea is for:

1. I configure my browser to hit the local proxy at, say, `http://localhost:8080/myproxy`
2. In my browser I go to a website, say, `http://example.com`
3. The browser passes the HTTP request (for `http://example.com`) off to the proxy, again running at `http://localhost:8080/myproxy`
4. The proxy (depending on the construct/mechanism used and how its configured to behave) may or may not inspect/do things with this request

   - For example, if the proxy is configured to act as a cache for static resources, it might inspect the request to see if its requesting a document (JS file, CSS file, IMG file, etc.) that it has previously cached. If it is a request for a cached document, we can short circuit (bypass the target site altogether) and just send the response (file) back to the browser
5. The proxy forwards the (or makes a brand new - **???**) request to the target site (`http://example.com`)
6. The target site sends back an HTTP response to the proxy
7. The proxy (depending on the construct/mechanism used and how its configured to behave) may or may not inspect/do things with this response

   - For example, if the proxy has been configured to scan for malicious malware, we might inspect the response for binary data, and if detected, send the binary response off to some 3rd party scanner tool for a pass/fail analysis, etc.
8. The proxy sends an HTTP response back to the browser

I'm leaning towards a servlet filter or Spring controller method, but not sure which is appropriate for presenting these kinds of capabilities. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For learning purposes, you probably want to avoid Spring and just start by implementing a simple HttpServlet. From there you will be able to inspect the HttpServletRequest object do any number of things including forwarding it. You could implement caching logic in the servlet itself, however, it probably makes sense to add a ServletFilter that enhances the servlet with caching behavior.